# Swap partition not mounted on boot

Tags: systemd, swap, sles

I'm having issues with a fresh SLES12 install and swap not mounting.
It's a DL360 G6 server with P410 and 2x 146GB drives in RAID1.
The single /dev/sda has MBR with sda1 for swap and sda2 for ext4 root partition.

systemd 210-95.1

Basically i'm not getting swap mounted on startup and only a manual `swapon` helps.

```
# journalctl
systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /dev/disk/by-uuid/307a84ab-a6cc-40f0-a84e-559aa99f364d.
systemd[1]: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-307a84ab\x2da6cc\x2d40f0\x2da84e\x2d559aa99f364d.device/start timed out.
systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-307a84ab\x2da6cc\x2d40f0\x2da84e\x2d559aa99f364d.device.
# systemctl restart dev-disk-by\\x2duuid-307a84ab\\x2da6cc\\x2d40f0\\x2da84e\\x2d559aa99f364d.swap
A dependency job for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-307a84ab\x2da6cc\x2d40f0\x2da84e\x2d559aa99f364d.swap failed. See 'journalctl -xn' for details.


# cat /etc/fstab
UUID=7b830caa-bca2-4617-b8cd-3145726c288a                       /                    ext4       acl,user_xattr        1 1
#/dev/sda1 swap                 swap       defaults              0 0
UUID=307a84ab-a6cc-40f0-a84e-559aa99f364d                      swap                 swap       defaults              0 0
```

I know there were issues with swap not working in systemd when GPT is used, but i'm clueless here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After upgrading to SLES12 SP1 there are no issues.
I didn't really bother to investigate which fix was responsible tho.